# How to replace a div content with another and then be able to retrieve the contents of the first div?

Tags: jquery

I wrote a jQuery function to replace the contents of a div with id quotecontact with another div of id quotenext on clicking a link of 'NEXT' in the div#quotecontact. It works fine.But I have a link of 'BACK' in my div#quotenext which needs to link to quotecontact div but it doesn't work. I will put my code below, let me know where I am wrong.

```
<div class="slidingDiv">
<div id="quotecontact" style="display:none >     
<a href="#" class="nextquote" data-target="quotenext" style="color:#000;font-size:19px">
                                                        NEXT
                                                        </a>
</div>
<div id="quotenext" style="display:none;">
<a href="#" class="nextquote" data-target="quotecontact" style="color:#000;font-size:19px">
                                                          < BACK
                                                        </a>
</div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(".nextquote").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $j(".slidingDiv").html($j("#"+$j(this).data('target')).html());
    $j(".slidingDiv").show("slide", {
        direction: "right"
    }, 200);
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Your issue is not resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are completely removing the current div `quoteContact` from DOM once clicked on `Next` so there is no way it will work if you click on Back as you are trying to show a div that doesn't exits in DOM anymore. You need to instead hide / and show them. or create them dynamically of you can't keep all in DOM. Here is a write up for that. And see [Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/jhBue/).

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(".slidingDiv").on('click', '.nextquote', function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    $j(this).closest('div').hide("slide", {
        direction: "right"
    }, 200);

    $j("#" + $j(this).data('target')).show("slide", {
        direction: "right"
    }, 200);

});
```

Comment: PSL : I tried your code but it doesn't seem to work.It creates a div below quotecontact on clicking NEXT and back doesnt seem to work

Comment: @Leah Did u check the fiddle? It doesnt create any divs, just toggling them.

Comment: Back doesn't take me back to quotecontact either.I have lot of div and html inside quotecontact and quotenext div, could that be creating the problem?

Comment: I did see it in fiddle but for me the div quotenext is coming  below quotecontact instead of replacing it, why could that be? And also when you put $(this).closest('div'), will it hide only the previous div?

Comment: ok, i get it $(this).closest('div').hide is used to hide the div with the clickable link but somehow it doesnt seem to work in my code

Comment: @Leah Can you post your html in a fiddle so that i can try to help. My example is based on the html yuo have n your question.

Comment: Thanks for replying.I have put my code in jsfiddle, can you let me know what is wrong? The code is here in http://jsfiddle.net/VsUpV/

Comment: You are using very old jquery version 1.3.2 in the fiddle, is your jquery verison this old?

Comment: But that is only making the instant quote button to silde down and up

Comment: I have even http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js in my code but forgot to include it here

Comment: See if this works, you can take the flipping section alone and plug it in... If helpful please `Mark the answer` which will get you 2 rep too and will let others know that this has been answered.

Comment: Have you  just changed the jquery version to jquery ui 1.9.2 and changed the closest('div') to closest('div.slide')

Comment: I have added a class to your divs with the name slide, so that it is easy to catch it specifically...

Comment: Is this what you were after? By the way in Fiddler you can just select Jquery on the left hand side itself. no need to add it as external resources.

Comment: I see now that you added a class slide.I couldnt slect a particular jquery file, thats y i went for external resources

Comment: Its on the left side of the fiddle, first dropdown... Is it working now? If so please mark this as answer. ALso do not use <, > as inner text you should use &lt; &gt;

Comment: I tried adding a class slide to quotesent to get to display another div which says message sent successfully on clicking submit but the message doesn't get displayed

Comment: So u have 3 layer nav? Next, Back and Submit...? and it belongs to the same div?

Comment: can you please give me the full link for jquery ui 1.9.2

Comment: This is the latest script available in jquery website. http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js

Comment: Hey PSL,have you just given jquery ui 1.9.2 cause when i give that alone for script src on my website the 'instant quote' option doesnt work.I need to give jquery 1.9.1 for it to work.Am i giving something wrong in the link for jquery ui 1.9.2? this is the link i am giving src=" http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"

Comment: You need to include jquery first and then jquery ui... What is the error that you are getting.. ? .

Comment: No error, if i dont include jquery 1.9.1, the instant quote link doesnt slide down to reveal the sliding div

Comment: you can see my website in blacknova.com.au

Comment: -I got it working!!I had copied the javascript from jsfiddle without tidy up , so i guess it included some special characters in my code which couldnt be seen in the text editor.I solved that problem and voila , the code works!!!Thanks a ton for the help!!

Comment: Wow great news.... :) Glad that i could be of some help!!! Your Site looks great...

Answer (score 0):

You need another container to put in your old data on clicking next. Then just pull that data and plug it in on clicking back.

//on click back
jQuery('#current').html(#('#old').html());

Then do the necessary logic to handle your next and stuff.

Comment: Sorry,I am not sure how to do assign old data into another container ,so is that assigning one div to another?